# How to deal with special characters in an Excel vlookup in order to display properly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, special-characters, validation

I have cells with validation values set to a list of some *Wingdings* characters, and these cells use the *Wingdings* font:

[image: cells with validation values and validation criteria]

[image: "Choix_coches" list used fas validation criteria]

If I use the combo validation by hand to set a value, it works perfectly.

But if I use a `vlookup` using as a value the result of some function between {empty, VRAI=TRUE, FAUX=FALSE}, named `xProcessus`, and as a range the previous list with a first column corresponding to these values, named `coches`, formala is: `=vlookup(xProcessus;coches;2;FAUX)`

[image]

I have strange results:

[image]

I have tried other formula without `vlookup` like `=car(254)` , so this is not the problem. What's wrong please?

Comment: If I'm not wrong to get these Check boxes you have used  font like Wingdings,, please [edit] your post and share some sample data with us also the formula you have tried so far, will help us to fix the issue!

Comment: Did you enable ActiveX controls settings in Excel? Go to File- Options- Trust Center- Trust Center Settings...- ActiveX Settings- select the forth option: Enable all controls without restrictions and without prompting

Comment: @Lee, I tried but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

When one uses `VLOOKUP()` using FALSE for the fourth parameter, ans their lookup fails EVEN THOUGH the appearance of the data in the lookup column and basic tests on it suggest the lookup value and the lookup column's value are identical... and the lookup fails, it is almost always the case that the lookup value and the lookup column's value are NOT, in fact, identical.

Given the characters shown for the lookup with xProcessus and so on look identical, it looks a lot like the formula's output is identical for all three cases and therefore, since the input differs yet returns the same result, that the lookup either doesn't see the inputs as differing from each other, or has an error (not an Excel !ERROR#, just an error) that happens when the type of failure (whatever it is) happens controlling the output.

Most often this appears "in the wild" with either real numbers for one of the values but a text formatted "number" for the other, hence the mismatch, or a clean value (e.g.:  it REALLY IS just what it looks like) for one being matched against a polluted value (e.g.:  it is NOT really just what it looks like (as in it is a "5" and a non-displaying character being matched against only a "5", something often encountered with one of the values being scraped from a website)).

You do not present actual (and discernible) data, so one simply cannot say for sure. But again, this problem is ALMOST ALWAYS due to this cause.

Examine the lookup output, the output of xProcessus. For instance, you could simply fill cells with its output until you had all the possible outputs, then copy them and paste them AS VALUES to a set of other cells. Then open one that you know to have failed in the `VLLOOKUP()` (you could just get this one output, then copied and pasted as a value, but it'd be handier maybe to have more to examine if nothing stands out to you at first so...) using F2 and Ctrl-Home to get to the start of the value in the editor, and look for obvious issues like " 1" being the output, having that space to start it while perhaps the lookup column has the bare digit. Use the right arrow to move SLOWLY character by character in what you see. Watch carefully as you are looking for characters that may have no width, so just a slight flash of the cursor happens while it does not move to the right. Anything that doesn't seem to belong.

Mind you, that's a general approach for the more common way this issue arises. Without literal examples, one can only guess at things.

BUT, it seems far likelier that your situation involves xProcessus passing not just a value or character of some kind to Excel to use in `VLOOKUP()` but rather a formatting of it as well. And that formatting is creating the difference Excel sees in the lookup value vs. the lookup column's value. The only real solution would be (since one likely cannot delve deeply into whatever xProcessus does) to reformat the lookup column values to match the formatting xProcessus includes.

The only other angle that comes to mind is evaluating the character returned. Looks like you are seeking characters 111, 253, and 254 but are getting character 61. (or either of the other two sets, 6Exx or 6dxx). No obvious offsetting going on there as the same 61 is returned by the function, not 61 and, say, 202 and 203. What kind of input to xProcessus could lead to it returning 61 instead of 111, 253, and 254. If it were `VLOOKUP()` returning the 61 by finding it in column 2 of the lookup range, that lookup range would have to contain just the 61's and it should have been obvious to you what's wrong, so it can't be the function, but rather wrong input if this angle is productive.) So some failure of xProcessus causes it to return 61 as if it were an error code. Alternatively, maybe it IS the lookup table's column 2 if perhaps the table contains a line that has 61 in its column 2. It would STILL come down to "what and why" for xProcessus.

The fact that hand entries ("hardcoded" entries) do not cause the problem also requires that the problem be in xProcessus' output, NOT in the coches data. (And, lest it has not been understood from the above, NOT in `VLOOKUP()` either.) So set up the outputs from xProcessus like mentioned a couple paragraphs ago and copy and paste them, as values, somewhere handy and start looking at them pretty critically. Examine the coches table too, for interest if nothing else, as it would be interesting to see why, EXACTLY, the 61 is being returned. What is is column 1 of the line with 61 in its column 2? Not only might it help, but following little details like that for intellectual reasons is how you build the knowledge that lets you suss out subtle things in years to follow.